# Documentation for creating own Data Model

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1, extension-model

We are making an application which is for 95% within Tridion itself through GUI Extensions. The 5% that are stored external would need to be viewable and editable from within the CME. We were thinking that creating our own Data Models could help make this possible.

Unfortunately it is hard to find documentation about this. The Documentation on SDLLiveContent is rather limited and finding examples has left us with a unfruitful result. **Is there more in-depth documentation/examples about the capabilities of Data models available than those found on SDLLive?**

(I already have taken a look at the [ItemType Extending tutorial of UIBreadCore](http://tridion.uibeardcore.com/2014/03/itemtype/#more-192))

---

Besides the answers below I would still love to get my hands on some documentation about Data Models as that was my core question.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what you consider a "Data Model"? There are no restrictions on what kind of objects you can return (as long as the serializer can handle them), so I'm not sure what kind of guidance you are looking for.

Comment: On SDL Live I read that you can create your own data types (CME has cme:custompg, ...) on top of those that exist. If I am not mistaken you can give these their own behaviour both at Client and Server side.
The questions that should be answered by reading documentation are: How do I implement this behaviour (Especially at Server side) and what are the possibilities with this (without changing/editing core functionalities).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make external data visible in the CME I think you should use set up an External Content Library.

You can find information here (You need to provide User & Password):
[ECL Tutorial](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?c=t&action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DECL&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1411558111028&currentQuery=ECL&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7.xml&docid=GUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false)

Comment: Is ECL supported in Tridion 2011 SP1?

Comment: Not officially supported, if you are using Tridion 2011 SP1, I think the easiest is a Custom Page

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, another option might be a Custom Page.

I find this approach takes the integration work away and you can just focus on building a web app that works for what you need it to do - i.e. update some custom data in a custom database (if I understand correctly)